# Combining vNext and NodeJS Server

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, architecture, asp.net-core, babeljs

I have written a simple NodeJS application, (using Express, React & some client side bits).

Whilst I wrote most of it in VSCode, I would like to get the app back into VS2015 as I prefer the TFS integration from a source control perspective.

I wanted to know if there is a preferred mechanism to import such a project back into VS2015. At the moment I can see 3 options.

1. Create a new vNext ASP.NET app and import the client side code into that. This will allow the VS tooling to work more easily on that project (gulp, npm etc), but the template comes with IIS integration which I don't need. I see in the `project properties` I can setup a debug profile which runs a `.exe` which could probably kick off node and fire up a `server.js`. My questions with this option are:

   - This seems like removing baked in IIS functionality and working round things. The vNext template seem to bake the front end and back end together.
   - I'm not sure whether the Node server side of things should be a seperate project? part of the same project? and if separate, which would be the startup project?
2. Import the existing project as it stands (one project) and treat it as a single node app. This seems to give me some problems as I need to run babel for ES6 transpiling. But this could probably be circumvented.
3. Import the existing project and break it into server and client parts. The benefits of this is that I'd possibly be able to deploy the parts separately but I'd still need to shoehorn the non VS bits of the node app into VS.

Any thoughts or ideas in this area, I can't find any reasonable documentation which covers keeping a node server and using VS2015. 
The reason for keeping the node server side of things is that I have a series of node modules I don't think have sensible C# equivalents which can be packaged and deployed so easily.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Node.js Tools for VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx)?

Comment: I have the node tools downloaded and installed them, unfortunately when I tried to create a project from the existing code VS just kept crashing.

Comment: I've persisted and managed to get Node tools to import my project, but it just slams it all in one project which is basically my option #2 in the list of the OP. It doesn't build or pickup my gulp tasks automatically and includes my bower_components folders. I will have a go cleaning it up, but doesn't seem to gain me much over just creating a blank project and importing the files.